# How to kill a multiprocessing.Process on a if condition

Tags: process

```
from multiprocessing import Process
a = '''This can be either 0 or 1'''
def Function():
    while True:
        print('Hello world')
    
function = Process(target = Function)
if (a == 1):
    function.start()
elif (a == 0):
    function.kill()
```

How do i make it so that when the value of a is 1 the process automatically kills itself. Doing it this way brings up an error saying 'function has no attribute kill'

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written, if the variable a is set to 0 it will bring up the error saying 'NoneType object has no attribute kill'. It is caused because it tries to kill a process which is not started yet.

Comment: Actually i am doing this with a raspberry pi. The code is huge so cannot be uploaded here. After i start the process, I use pynput to detect keypress. If key 'q' is pressed function is supposed to get killed but shows and error and continues doings its thing